# Explaination of this lambda function please?

Tags: python, lambda

I sorted a list of tuples using `sorted(list_of_tuples, key = lambda tup: tup[1])` from code I found on the internet. I don't understand how the lambda function works in this command. Is the lambda function returning the first index of the tuple? Why `tup` instead of `tuple`? What does the first `tup` before the `:` denote? Is that the parameter being passed in? Does Lambda functions evaluate the right side of `:` and return it?

I found explanation of lambda functions on StackOverflow where people wrote out the Lambda function out in the 'not functional' manner as comparison but I don't really understand which parts are equivalent to which parts.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a `lambda` is an inline function, so you can rewrite it longhand like this:

```
def sortkey(tup):
    return tup[1]

sorted(list_of_tuples, key=sortkey)
```

Now you see the `tup` before the colon is the **argument** to the function, and `tup[1]` returns the *second* element (first being `tup[0]`)

This lambda is the `key` to the sort function, meaning you're sorting by the second of each element of the `list_of_tuples`. `sorted()` passes each element into the `key` function, sorting *by the return value of said function*

As pointed out by @kojiro, a built-in function exists for this in the `operator` module, called [`itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). You pass an index to that function, and it returns a function which does what your lambda does

Example demonstrating how a key is only called once:

```
>>> def sortkey(x):
...     print x
...     return x

>>> inputlist = range(5)
>>> random.shuffle(inputlist)
>>> sorted(inputlist, key=sortkey)
0
3
4
2
1
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Another way to write this lambda would be [`operator.itemgetter(1)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: very true, but not OP's question

Comment: Right, but possibly useful to future readers who stumble upon this answer.

Comment: @mhlester so how does Python know to pass in the tuple as the parameter of the lambda function? Why doesn't it feed in the entire list of tuples?

Comment: It might be illustrative to replace the lambda with a function that prints its argument list before returning the item gotten.

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) explain it:

> Small anonymous functions can be created with the `lambda` keyword. This function returns the sum of its two arguments: `lambda a, b: a+b`. Lambda functions can be used wherever function objects are required. They are syntactically restricted to a single expression. Semantically, they are just syntactic sugar for a normal function definition.

So, in other words:

```
x = lambda AAAA: EEEE
```

is nearly equivalent to

```
def x(AAAA):
    return EEEE
```

where `AAAA` are the parameters and `EEEE` is an expression.

Why nearly equivalent? Because the underlying function objects have different names: in the `def` case, it is `x`, while in the `lambda` case, it is `<lambda>`.